# How to find/see tempdb in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2017, tempdb

Should I expect to be able to see tempdb tables in SSMS?

e.g. If I run this code, should I expect to be able to see the table in SSMS?

```
-- Drop the table if it already exists    
IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempPasswords')) IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempPasswords

CREATE TABLE #TempPasswords (
    MemberNo    INT,
    Password    nvarchar(120),
    NewPassword varbinary(MAX)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to see the temp DB but the name only. To see  temp DB follow the instruction as per the image. After running the query right click on the **Temporary Tables** and Refresh .

[image]

Comment: I noted that actions that are normally available with tables are not available within SSMS with temp tables .. via SSMS menus .. e.g. "Select Top 1000 Rows" ..

Answer (score 2):

Only if you run your code snippet in SSMS. In that session you will be able to execute

T-SQL that include your temp table.

In order to see temp tables globally use two hashes ##.